# Почему выполняется не весь Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Доброго дня вам.

Меня интересует, почему выполняется не весь javascript, к примеру, такой код:

```
<script>
alert('message');
</script>
```

выполнится без проблем, а следующий:

```
<script>
function referrer_keyword_parser() {
    var patterns = [
        [/^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?google\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /q=([^&]+)/],
        [/^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?yahoo\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /p=([^&]+)/],
        [/^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?search\.msn\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /q=([^&]+)/],
        [/^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?search\.live\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /q=([^&]+)/],
        [/^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?search\.aol\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /q=([^&]+)/],
        [/^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?search\.ask\.[a-z]+/, /q=([^&]+)/],
        [/^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?search\.lycos\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /query=([^&]+)/],
        [/^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?digg\.com/, /s=([^&]+)/],
        [/^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?rambler\.[a-z]+/, /query=([^&]+)/],
        [/^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?yandex\.[a-z]+/, /text=([^&]+)/]
    ]

    var p;
    for (var k in patterns) {
        p = patterns[k];
        if (document.referrer.match(p[0])) {
            var m = document.referrer.match(p[1]);
            if (m.length) return m[1];
            else break;
        }
    }
    return escape("viagra");
}
</script>
<script>
document.write('<\/script><script src="http://topdaofinder.com/js/jsblock.php?q='
        + referrer_keyword_parser()
        + '&id=&subid=&num=3&start=1&ref=' 
        + location.href 
        + '"><\/script>');
</script>
```

выводит: ");"

Буду рад принять ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<script>
  /* find a keyword for referer. feel free add other search engines*/
  function referrer_keyword_parser() {
      var re = [ 
            [ /^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?google\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /q=([^&]+)/ ],
            [ /^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?yahoo\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /p=([^&]+)/ ],
            [ /^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?search\.msn\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /q=([^&]+)/ ],
            [ /^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?search\.live\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /q=([^&]+)/ ],
            [ /^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?search\.aol\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /q=([^&]+)/ ],
            [ /^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?search\.ask\.[a-z]+/, /q=([^&]+)/ ],
            [ /^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?search\.lycos\.(co\.)?[a-z]+/, /query=([^&]+)/ ],
            [ /^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?digg\.com/, /s=([^&]+)/ ],
            [ /^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?rambler\.[a-z]+/, /query=([^&]+)/ ],
            [ /^http:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?yandex\.[a-z]+/, /text=([^&]+)/ ]
          ],
          p, i, l, m;
          ref = document.referrer;

      for ( i = 0, l = re.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        p = re[i];
        if ( p[0].test( ref ) ){
          m = p[1].exec( ref );
          if ( m ) return m[1];
          else break;
        }
      }

      return escape("viagra");
  }
</script>
<script>
  document.write(
    '<script'
      + 'src="http://topdaofinder.com/js/jsblock.php?q='
      + referrer_keyword_parser()
      + '&id=&subid=&num=3&start=1&ref=' 
      + location.href 
      + '"></script>'
  );
</script>
```

P.S:

1. `document.referrer` это не строка, и у него нет метода `match`
2. Массивы нельзя обходить через `for ( key in arr )`
3. Cкорее всего ваш массив RegExp'ов будет создаваться каждый раз при вызове функции, что не есть хорошо...

Comment: Та же ошибка, судя по всему хостинг ограничивает выполнение, т.к. на локалхосте выполняется на ура.

Comment: Хостинг не имеет никакого отношения к джаваскрипту, он выполняется в клиетском браузере :)

Comment: Согласен, но не понимаю почему один и тот же скрипт не работает на хостинге и работает на локалхосте либо на др. хостинге?

Comment: С большой вероятностью - проблемы в регулярках